# Help converting PHP eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I am wondering if someone could please help me convert a piece of PHP code that is now deprecated.

Here is the single line I am trying to convert:

```
if(eregi(trim ($request_url_handler[$x]),$this->sys_request_url) && $this->id_found == 0){
```

It is part of a function that return the configuration settings for a website. Below is the whole function.

```
// GET CORRECT CONFIG FROM DATABASE
function get_config($db)
{
    global $tbl_prefix;
    $db->query("SELECT cid,urls FROM ".$tbl_prefix."sys_config ORDER BY cid");

    while($db->next_record()){
        $request_url_handler = explode("\n",$db->f("urls"));
        if(empty($request_url_handler[0])) {
            $request_url_handler[0] = "@";
            $this->id_found = 2;
        }

        for($x=0; $x<count($request_url_handler); $x++) {
            if(empty($request_url_handler[$x])) {
                $request_url_handler[$x] = "@";
            }
            if(eregi(trim($request_url_handler[$x]),$this->sys_request_url) && $this->id_found == 0) {
                $this->set_config($db,$db->f("cid"));
                $this->id_found = 1;
            }
        }

        if($this->id_found == 1) {
            return($this->sys_config_vars);
        }
    }

    $this->set_config($db,"");
    return($this->sys_config_vars);
}
```

Any help would be great ly appreciated. I only found the the eregi function was deprecated since I updated XAMPP to 1.7.3.

Comment: See ["How to change PHP's eregi to preg_match"](http://customphpfunctions.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-change-phps-eregi-to-pregmatch.html) to get an idea about both functions and the for replacing depreciated one with other.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing:

```
if(eregi(trim($request_url_handler[$x]),$this->sys_request_url) && $this->id_found == 0) {
```

with:

```
$request_url_handler[$x] = trim($request_url_handler[$x]);
if( preg_match("/$request_url_handler[$x]/i",$this->sys_request_url) && $this->id_found == 0) {
```

`eregi` is deprecated and we need to use `preg_match` with the `i` option as its replacement.

**In general**

```
eregi($regex,$input)
```

can be replaced with:

```
preg_match("/$regex/i",$input)
```

**EDIT:**

Its assumed that `$regex` above does not contain any `/` which is used as **delimiters**. If it does then you'll have to use a different delimiter say `@` or `#` or `|` not contained in `$regex`

```
preg_match("#$regex#i",$input)
```

Alternatively you can also escape all the occurrences of the delimiter in the `$regex`.

Comment: Thanks a million for helping me out on this matter. It comes up with an error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\VirtualCMS\system\class_config.php  on line 57

Comment: You will need to replace '/' with '\/' in case the regex contains a slash.

Comment: @Jason: I've updated my answer. Try using a different delimiter in preg_match.

Comment: Aah thanks unicornaddict, changing the delimeter worked a treat, sorry for the trouble, thanks for the help and knowledge.